# Do dota coaches get paid

Tags: dota-2, competitive-gaming

Do Dota coaches get paid and what percentage of winnings?  If a team win TI do coaches get paid a percent too?  I think if they get paid they would try harder.

Answer (score 3):

> Do Dota coaches get paid and what percentage of winnings?

Yes, coaches for pro teams get paid. The percentage depends on their ability to negotiate beforehand.

> If a team win TI do coaches get paid a percent too?

Either the percentage is negotiated before TI (for the length of their contract) or involves a separate negotiation in the event that they make TI (if they're a lower tier team). The coach's ability to get a portion of the TI prizepool depends on their ability to negotiate; they may forgo the percentage for a flat fee. This is kind of less specific to Dota and more to jobs in general; it's all their ability to negotiate.